# How to Turn Off a Program Running from .bash_profile

Tags: shell, command-line, bash

I am working with a Raspberry Pi running linux, and have modified the .bash_profile file in order to a run a program I've made automatically upon login. This works great, but I was wondering how to turn the program off, since for ctrl+c I would need to be running the program in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Kill` to terminate program by its process Id, Top command will list all the processes, You can also use Pkill, which will Terminate the process by its name.

-9 option forces process to shut down, so its very commonly used.

Example:

kill -9 "Process ID without Quotation marks"

pkill -9 "Name with Quotation marks (Case Sensitive)"

---

Check [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ps-kill-and-nice-to-manage-processes-in-linux).

Answer (score 1):

I always use

> pkill - f processname